# Trying to change the style of every element in an array using ForEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have a function which creates new divs when a certain condition met.
Once those divs are created I store them in an array using .push() as you see below:

```
function SnakeBody(){
  BodySnake = document.createElement("div");
  tabuleiro.appendChild(BodySnake); 
  BodySnake.classList.add("snakeBody");
  StorePositions.push(BodySnake) ; 
}
```

After that , when another condition is met I try to change a style element on each of those divs using ForEach() on the array those divs were stored , as you see below :

```
function SnakeBodyLeft(){
  StorePositions.forEach(element => {
    BodySnake.style.gridRowStart = (Initial_y + y);
    BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+1 ;
  });
};
```

The idea is:

1 - Use ForEach() to run a function for each element on the array.

2 - The function runned should change the value/style of every element on the array.

However this is isnt working and I can't see what I'am missing ??

Comment: Change BodySnake.style.gridRowStart to element.style.gridRowStart

Comment: `BodySnake.style` should be `element.style`, because that's what you named it

Comment: If you use a proper IDE for writing your code, it indicates that `element` is an unused variable by darkening it. Can be very helpful for finding mistakes like that.

Comment: Omg ! Thank you so much , I have been here so long and I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `StorePositions.forEach(...)` you must use `element`. `BodySnake` can only be accessed in the `function SnakeBody()`.